# Internet Explorer not Updating on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I recently set up two new servers running 2008 R2.  On one of these servers I found that Internet Explorer was not updating.  After supposedly installing the update, it still shows IE 8 as the browser.  I attempted to install the Offline IE 11 installer.  I also, used command line to remove IE 8 and any partial installs of other versions.  I installed IE 11 using the offline installer, and when opening IE, I found it was running 8.  Any ideas on getting this properly updated?  Thanks!

Comment: @Ari Winokur, Have you checked your Windows Update log? If so, what does it say in there? that might give you an indication as to why it is failing to install.

Comment: Have all the prerequisite hotfixes been installed? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2847882/prerequisite-updates-for-internet-explorer-11

Comment: I will thoroughly check these by downloading and attempting to install.  Bear in mind that Windows Updates cannot find any other updates needed and appears to install IE 10 without errors. Also IE 11 offline installer runs without errors.

Comment: @TeNaJSystems The update installs without errors and the offline installer for IE 11 does the same.  The windows updates local log shows a successful install as well.

Comment: Check %systemroot%\IE11_main.log for additional information. You may want to include that in your question.

Comment: @GregAskew It looks like the server was missing one of those hotfixes.  I ran all of them and most said that they were not applicable or already installed, but a couple installed.  After a restart I ran the IE 11 offline installer and restarted one more time.  It appears that the install is sticking now.  Thank you again for that link!

On a side note, it is very interesting that this particular server could not install updates properly while the other one did. I guess it was just a weird hiccup when updating the new install.